# Virtual Box is not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

This error code pops up, please give me advice on what to do. I don't know how to start up the virtual machine without running into an error. Is there a command line a can use to address this?

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine windows.

The virtual machine 'windows' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

Comment: Please [edit your previous question](https://askubuntu.com/q/916944/301745), do not post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
apt-get update && apt-get install virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y
modprobe vboxdrv
```

Comment: I dont know how to use modprobe or virtualbox-qt headers